# How to check if two nodes are cousins in binary tree in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, array-algorithms

In a binary tree, the root node is at depth 0, and children of each depth k node are at depth k+1.

Two nodes of a binary tree are cousins if they have the same depth, but have different parents.

We are given the root of a binary tree with unique values, and the values x and y of two different nodes in the tree.

Return true if and only if the nodes corresponding to the values x and y are cousins.

Example 1:
[click for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzwAy.png)

Input: root = [1,2,3,4], x = 4, y = 3
Output: false
Example 2:

Input: root = [1,2,3,null,4,null,5], x = 5, y = 4
Output: true

Comment: please edit your post: give code of what you tried so far / what is not working

Comment: Hi, your examples could be clearer.  It would also help if you show what algorithm you have developed so far instead of just asking for the answer.  Maybe share the code you have to find the depth of an arbitrary node in your tree.

Comment: It's not clear what you consider to be "cousins". Are all nodes at the same level "cousins", or only those nodes that share the same grandparent?

Comment: I have added example

Comment: I have posted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

->using inorder
->getting depth for left and right sub trees separately

```
public boolean isCousins(TreeNode root, int x, int y) {
    int[] res = new int[5];
    inorder(root.left,x,y,0,root,res);
    inorder(root.right,x,y,0,root,res);
    if(res[1] != res[3] && res[2] == res[4])
        return true;
    return false;
}

public void inorder(TreeNode node, int x, int y,int dep, TreeNode parent, int[] res){
    if(node == null)
        return;
    dep = dep + 1;
    inorder(node.left, x, y, dep, node, res);

    if(node.val == x){
        res[1] = parent.val;
        res[2] = dep;
        return;
    }
    else if(node.val == y){
        res[3] = parent.val;
        res[4] = dep;
        return;
    }

    inorder(node.right, x ,y, dep, node, res);
}
```

}